# Python Socket Server Isn't Accepting Connections From Outside The Local WIFI Network

Tags: python, python-sockets

I created a simple messaging app and I'm trying to make it so people outside my home network can join. I port forwarded the machine its running on. I made sure that the Iv4 and port match the settings on the Xfinity gateway. Even then its still not working outside my Home network. Is there something else I have to do to make it work?

Here is the server code. Don't know if it helps though.

```
import threading
import socket

host = "IV4 HERE"
port = PORT HERE

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen() 

clients = []
nicknames = []

def brodcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message) 

def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            brodcast(message)
        except:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            brodcast(f'''
            {nickname} left the chat'''.encode('ascii')) 
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break 

def recive():
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print(f"Connected with {str(address)}")
        client.send('NICK'.encode('ascii'))
        nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)
        print(f'{nickname} joined the chat!')
        brodcast(f'{nickname} joined the chat!'.encode('ascii'))
        client.send('Connected to the chat'.encode('ascii'))

        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()

recive()
```

Comment: Port forwarding on the router is one half of the equation. Did you configure your system firewall too? That's bitten me a few times.

Comment: You should always bind a listening socket to 0.0.0.0 rather than any specific IP address, unless you know exactly why you're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you are looking for. But tunnels can help you out here.

I learned about them from this video by Fireship.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlBOpNLFUC0

Here's a summary of the steps:

1. Use [CloudFlare Tunnels](https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/how-to/preview-with-cloudflare-tunnel) or [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)
2. download the cloudflare tunnel cli tool
3. run the tunnel command and point it to the localhost port you want to serve

it will spit out a url where now anybody can view your localhost on the internet